# Two different type indexed array in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, dereference

I need an array type for storing objects. But i need two types of access property like this:

array[0] >>> object1

array["a"] >>> object1

This means index 0 (an integer ) and index a (a string) dereferences same object in the array. For storing objects, i think we need collections but how can i do access property that i mentioned above?

Comment: Does 1 map to "b", 2 to "c", and so on, or is it arbitrary access by number and string that may not relate to each other by a pattern?

Comment: 0 map to a string key, 1 map to another string key and so on but they shows same object in the array

Comment: How often do you add to/remove elements from that "map" and how will you do it - by index or by key? As already stated in the answers, you could create a class that is a composition of a list and a map, but the answer to the above question could provide a hint for implementation details (i.e. whether to store key->index or index->key mapping for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a map from the string keys to the numeric keys:

```
Map<String, Integer> keyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
keyMap.put("a", o);
// etc
```

Then create a List of your objects, where MyObject is the value type:

```
List<MyObject> theList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

Access by integer:

```
MyObject obj = theList.get(0);
```

Access by String

```
MyObject obj = theList.get(keyMap.get("a"));
```

This requires maintaining your key data structure, but allows for access of your values from one data structure.

You can encapsulte that is in a class, if you like:

```
public class IntAndStringMap<V> {
    private Map<String, Integer> keyMap;

    private List<V> theList;

    public IntAndStringMap() {
        keyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        theList = new ArrayList<V>();
    }

    public void put(int intKey, String stringKey, V value) {
        keyMap.put(stringKey, intKey);
        theList.ensureCapacity(intKey + 1); // ensure no IndexOutOfBoundsException
        theList.set(intKey, value);
    }

    public V get(int intKey) {
        return theList.get(intKey);
    }

    public V get(String stringKey) {
        return theList.get(keyMap.get(stringKey));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays only support indecies.

It appears you what to be able to look up an object by index and by key. In which case I suggest you have two collections. One for each type of lookup.

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMapList<MyObject>():

// array[0] >>> object1
MyObject object0 = list.get(0);

// array["a"] >>> object1
MyObject objectA = map.get("a");
```

Comment: How can we combine them into one? Should we override ArrayList add, get etc.. methods?

Comment: @mausmust: No, don't inherit when you can use composition. You could create a custom type containing both a list and a map with a `add(key, value)`, `get(index)` and `get(key)` methods.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them into one?  If you have a database with two ways of performing a lookup, you have two indecies.  In any case, you cannot combine add, get and many others as they take different arguments.  If you really must do this, you can create a wrapper to combine both.